# Laravel import excel file to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6, laravel-excel

When I import the excel file to the database, the file imported to the database but it inserts together with the excel first row which is the column name, I don't know how to make it upload only the data start from the second row.

Below is the code that I use in the controller to import

```
public function import()
{
    Excel::import(new StudentImport,request()->file('file'));

    return redirect('/admin/dashboard')->with('flash_message_success','Upload successful');
}
```

I expected the data inserted to the database starting from the second row and skip the first row which is the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the headingRow

```
 public function headingRow(): int
 {
    return 1;
 }
```

and your import class will be

```
class StudentImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow{}
```

Refer [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html#heading-row-on-different-row)